# How can I restore the Time Machine exclusion list from a Time Machine backup?

Tags: time-machine, macos

I reinstalled Yosemite clean, reformatting the disk before. I want to recover the Time Machine settings, specially the exclusion list, from the time machine backup of Maverics.

Any idea how to do it?

I copied `com.apple.TimeMachine.plist` located in `/Library/Preferences/` but it didn't work.

any other idea?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open that plist from your previous install and look for "SkipPaths". Under that key you should find the exclusion paths you had set on your previous install.

For example from my own it looks like this:

```
<key>SkipPaths</key>
<array>
    <string>~alistair/Documents/Virtual Machines</string>
    <string>~alistair/Downloads</string>
</array>
```

That would at least tell you which paths you had excluded before so you could re-add them through the Time Machine preferences pane in System Preferences.

Comment: Thanks. I could read the directories, and enter them manually in the system preferences tab. Thanks.